# Bash does not showing stdout properly

Tags: c, file

I am trying to learn i/o in Linux. I wrote following code to read my stdin and write to stdout:

```c
int main(int argc,char **argv){
    int n;
    int acc= 0;
    rio_t rio;
    char buf[MAXLINE];
    char *readp = buf;

    rio_readinitb(&rio,STDIN_FILENO);
    while((n= rio_readlineb(&rio,readp,MAXLINE)) != 0){
        readp = readp +n;
        acc += n;
        write(STDOUT_FILENO,"Outputs\n",8);
        write(STDOUT_FILENO,"--------\n",9);
        rio_writen(STDOUT_FILENO,buf,acc);
    }
}
```

I am using CLion. When I run the code in debug mode, it works properly. However, when I run it in bash, the program gets stuck after a few inputs.

I get rio prefixed functions from Computer Systems A Programmer's Perspective book.

```c
ssize_t rio_writen(int fd,void *usrbuf,size_t n){


    size_t nleft = n;
    ssize_t nwritten;
    char* bufp = usrbuf;


    while(nleft >0){
        if((nwritten = write(fd,bufp,nleft)) <= 0 ){
            if (errno = EINTR){
                nwritten = 0;
            }else{
                return -1;
            }
        }
        nleft -= nwritten;
        bufp += nwritten;
    }
    return n;
}

// Buffered I/O



void rio_readinitb(rio_t *rp,int fd){
    rp-> rio_fd = fd;
    rp-> rio_cnt = 0;
    rp-> rio_bufptr = rp->rio_buf;
}

static ssize_t rio_read(rio_t *rp,char *usrbuf,size_t n){
    /* Refill if buffer is empty*/
    while(rp->rio_cnt <= 0){
        rp->rio_cnt = read(rp->rio_fd,rp->rio_buf,sizeof(rp->rio_buf));

        if(rp->rio_cnt <0){
            if(errno != EINTR){
                return -1;
            }
        } else if(rp->rio_cnt == 0){
            return 0;
        }else {
            rp->rio_bufptr = rp->rio_buf;
        }
    }


    size_t cnt = rp->rio_cnt;
    if(n < rp->rio_cnt){
        cnt = n;
    }
    memcpy(usrbuf,rp->rio_bufptr,cnt);
    rp-> rio_bufptr += cnt;
    rp->rio_cnt -= cnt;

    return cnt;

}

ssize_t rio_readlineb(rio_t *rp,void *usrbuf,size_t maxlen){
    int n,rc;
    char* bufp = usrbuf;
    char c;

    for(n = 0;n<maxlen;n++){
        if((rc= rio_read(rp,&c,1))== 1){
            *bufp++ = c;
            if(c == '\n'){
                n++;
                break;
            }
        }else if(rc == 0){
            if(n==0){
                return 0;
            } else{
                break;
            }
        }else{
            return -1;
        }
    }
    *bufp = 0;
    return n;
}

ssize_t rio_readbnb(rio_t *rp,void* usrbuf,size_t n){
    size_t nleft = n;
    ssize_t nread;
    char *bufp = usrbuf;

    while(nleft > 0){
        if(nread = rio_read(rp,bufp,n) < 0){
            if (errno == EINTR){
                nread = 0;
            }else{
                return -1;
            }
        }else if(nread == 0){
            break;
        }
        nleft -= nread;
        bufp += nread;
    }

    return (n-nleft);
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are overflowing the buffer because you never set `readp` back to the start of the buffer.

Comment: Please include headers when posting a [mre] otherwise your program is incomplete.

Comment: I added the full code, It is working on debug mode in CLion. But If I use bash after some point I entered but it is not writing output.